class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x13d73fa) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer
I tried execute spark program in my springboot framework(mvn) project in IDEA, but I found the question below:
INFO
org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint -- Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
10:52:23.594 [main] INFO org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint -- BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x13d73fa) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x13d73fa
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:464)
    at SparkML.sparkML(SparkML.scala:33)
    at Demo$.main(Demo.scala:4)

Here is my total dependency:
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spark.version>3.5.0</spark.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.13</scala.version>
        <hadoop.version>3.3.2</hadoop.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spark dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Scala dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hadoop dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Spark MLlib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-spring-boot3-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--引入druid数据源-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

Then I searched the question and found that it maybe the conflict between java17 used in my sprintboot framework   and spark that caused the question.
At first, I adjust the version of spark from 3.2.3 to 3.5.0(spark 3.5.0 runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13 from apache document). However, the question still exists.
After that I tried the method others offered in the similar question in stackoverflow. I add vm potions in my configuration like the picture below
vm options
Here is the vm option:
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED


Could anyone help? Thanks a lot

What you already have is an --add-opens in your VM arguments for the package highlighted in the exception. Instead what you need is an --add-exports!

because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module

Adding an argument like the following shall help you with this(temporarily):
--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED

More on the difference between the two can be found here.
What's worth exploring is to upgrade your spark dependencies to the latest version supporting Java-17.

Thanks for your answer ! However,  I have changed the version of  springboot to 2.6.13 and jdk to java8. Thanks for your answer again!
